# Can someone suggest a one-line regex to parse out alphanumeric and optional numeric ids with either a - or / separator?

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm trying to parse a set of strings that follow the following patterns

```
{alpha-numeric-id}-{numeric-id}
```

or

```
{alpha-numeric-id}/{numeric-id}
```

1. The `alpha-numeric-id` can include the `-` character, and numbers
2. The `numeric-id` is always a number, and is optional.
3. The `alpha-numeric-id` and the `numeric-id` may either be separated by a `-` or `/`

I want to parse out the `alpha-numeric-id` and `numeric-id` (if it's there) in a single step.

#### Examples

```
'ThePixies1996' => { 1: 'ThePixies1996', 2: '' }
'7ThePixies' => { 1: '7ThePixies', 2: '' }
'The-Pixies' => { 1: 'The-Pixies', 2: '' }
'The-Pixies-1234567' => { 1: 'The-Pixies', 2: '1234567' }
'The-Pixies/1234567' => { 1: 'The-Pixies', 2: '1234567' }
```

So far the simplest way I have come up with is as follows:

```
const parse = str => {
  const numeric = str.match(/[-\/]([0-9]+)/)

  return numeric
    ? {
      numericId: numeric[1],
      alphaNumericId: str.slice(0, -1 * (numeric[1].length + 1))
    }
    : {
      numericId: '',
      alphaNumericId: str
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Try `^([\da-z-]+?)(?:[-/](\d+))?$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/TNgfyI/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(.+?)(?:[\/-](\d+))?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/PQSmaA/1/

Capture the `alphaNumericId` in a group by lazy-repeating any characters, then optionally have a group of a dash or forward slash, followed by digits captured in another group, the `numericId`. Destructure the match and assign a default value (the empty string) to the numericId to return the desired object quickly:

```js
const input = ['ThePixies1996',
'7ThePixies',
'The-Pixies',
'The-Pixies-1234567',
'The-Pixies/1234567'
];
function parse(str) {
  const [_, alphaNumericId, numericId = ''] = str.match(/(.+?)(?:[\/-](\d+))?$/);
  return { alphaNumericId, numericId };
}
console.log(
  input.map(parse)
);
```

That's assuming the inputs are always valid, like your `parse` function does. If they aren't and you need to test for whether the inputs are in the desired format as well, repeat the alphanumeric ID characters with a character set instead of `.`, and throw or something when the required format is not matched:

```js
const input = ['ThePixies1996',
'7ThePixies',
'The-Pixies',
'The-Pixies-1234567',
'The-Pixies/1234567',
'invalid/input/string'
];
function parse(str) {
   const match = str.match(/^([a-z\d-]+?)(?:[\/-](\d+))?$/i);
   if (!match) return 'INVALID';
   const [_, alphaNumericId, numericId = ''] = match;
  return { alphaNumericId, numericId };
}
console.log(
  input.map(parse)
);
```

Comment: Your current regex will have a match on `//////`.

Comment: I almost had that apart from not thinking of the `?:` part.  I should have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do !!!

Comment: @revo that's okay as there is no chance I'll be getting `//////` as input.

Comment: @DaveSag So you are not validating anything? How about `The-Pixies/`?

Comment: Likewise there is no chance I will ever get a lone trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression would be much more simpler if you know what you are going to do. Having said that, this would be a desirable solution:

```
^([\da-z-]+?)(?:[-/](\d+))?$
```

Explanation:

- `^` Match beginning of string
- `([\da-z-]+?)` Match and capture an alphanumeric string including `-` (non-greedy)
- `(?:[-/](\d+))?` Match a string starting with characters `-` or `/` that follows a sequence of digits (which is captured) optionally
- `$` End of string

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/TNgfyI/1)

JS code:

```js
var matches = [];
'The-Pixies/12345'.replace(/^([\da-z-]+?)(?:[-/](\d+))?$/ig, function(m, $1, $2) {
    matches.push($1, $2);
})

console.log(matches.filter(Boolean));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex in much simpler way

```
const parse = (data) => {
    let inx = data.lastIndexOf("-")
    if (inx === -1 || isNaN(data.slice(inx))){
        inx = data.lastIndexOf("/")  
    }
    return {
          numericId: data.slice(0, inx),
          alphaNumericId: data.slice(inx+1)
    }
}
```

Comment: The last `str` in your example should be `data`, but even with that corrected it fails on `'ThePixies1996` or `7ThePixies`.